# GPG: AllowSetForegroundWindow(13116) failed: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I'm trying to generate a key pair in GnuGPG and receiving "GPG: AllowSetForegroundWindow(13116) failed: The parameter is incorrect."

`Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number generator a better chance to gain enough entropy. gpg: AllowSetForegroundWindow(13116) failed: The parameter is incorrect. gpg: agent_genkey failed: Timeout Key generation failed: Timeout`

When I enter the command 'gpg --list-keys' the public key is there, but when I enter 'gpg --list-secret-keys' the private key is not listed.

I had read another post that stated "Checkout the taskbar. While creating the key you should get a (blinking) notification for pinentry - the tool to enter the passphrase. Under some circumstances Windows won't pop up that tool and you need to click on its icon in the taskbar."

I'm using a Windows command prompt which doesn't have a task bar.

The full list of commands used:

```
E:\Program Files\GnuPG\bin>gpg --full-generate-key
Please select what kind of key you want:
(1) RSA and RSA (default)
(2) DSA and Elgamal
(3) DSA (sign only)
(4) RSA (sign only)
(14) Existing key from card
Your selection? 1
RSA keys may be between 1024 and 4096 bits long.
What keysize do you want? (3072) 2048
Requested keysize is 2048 bits
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
     0 = key does not expire
  <n>  = key expires in n days
  <n>w = key expires in n weeks
  <n>m = key expires in n months
  <n>y = key expires in n years
  Key is valid for? (0) 365
  Key expires at 9/18/2024 2:50:27 PM Central Daylight Time
  Is this correct? (y/N) y

  GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

  Real name: TestKey
  Email address: myaddress@domain.ca
  Comment: test key
  You selected this USER-ID:
   "TestKey (test key) <myaddress@domain.ca>"

  Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
  We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to 
  perform
  some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize 
  the
  disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
  generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
  gpg: AllowSetForegroundWindow(13116) failed: The parameter is 
  incorrect.
  gpg: agent_genkey failed: Timeout
  Key generation failed: Timeout
```

Any ideas?